# Adding classes in application at run time

Tags: java

I have an abstract class in my software as follows:

```
public abstract class Foo {   
    public abstract addAlgo(Object o);  
}
```

I want to have different implementations of `Foo` by different people to be saved and run by my software dynamically on run time. I have a main class as follows:

```
public class Main {
    Foo f;
}
```

I want my users to give their implementations of `Foo` at run time. I am facing following difficulties:

1. How would the User be able to add his implementation class by GUI on run time?
2. How can I instantiate objects of user's implementation at run time in `Main` class? I want the user's implementation to be a permanent part of my software in the future, not just at the run time... i.e. I want my software to add functionality at run time and permanently store that functionality (i.e change in the `Main` class) ... actually I want to extend my software by user's day by day... Once the user will add his functionality class at run time then he would be able to view his object instantiation code in the `Main` class(automatically) as follows:

   ```
   public class Main {
       Foo f;

       main(...){

           MyAlgo O=new MyAlgo();//MyAlgo implements Foo actually
           f=O;
       }
   }
   ```

How can I do this?

Comment: About the first question, why not add a window in your GUI that lets the user create that object with his input? and on submit the system will create that object with the passed data and add it to main? With a Collection

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user to supply his implementation (and any helper classes, resources the may also belong there) in the form of .jar file, and use [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load the needed class by name. URLs can refer the local file in a way like

```
   new URL("file:///home/myJars/myjar.jar") // Linux
   new URL("file:///c:/myJars/myjar.jar");  // Windows
```

In more complex cases you may need to implement your own classloader that can easily convert arbitrary array of bytes into a working java class, as long as the internal format is correct. A good introductory lesson about classloaders can be found [here](http://isis.poly.edu/courses/cs916/Lectures/11-2.pdf).

Simply use some plain text file to remember the attached URLs between runs.

The simplest way is just to call the `loadClass(userClassName).newInstance()` on the URL classloader to obtain the instance of the object of the user-supplied class. The user class must have the parameter - less constructor for this to work.

Comment: The OP might also need to refractor his Main class to have a constructor or a setter to initialize the Foo. The way the main method is written in Main, there seems to be no way to swap an implementation unless the name of the new class that will be loaded will always be MyAlgo

Comment: The name of the user-supplied class must be in a string variable to pass to the classloader. It cannot be just in the code as it is not known at the compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`java.net.URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) in combination with a [java.util.ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to load the new class(es).

However there are some restrictions on the classes extending Foo, mainly there must be a constructor with no arguments (or default constructor). Additionally the jars have to contain a file `META-INF/services/<servicename>` where `<servicename>` is the full class name of the service , i.e. something like this: `mypackage.Foo`; This file has to contain a line with the full name of the classes in the jar, that implement the service and should be found by the `ServiceLoader`. In your case the file should look like this

#### META-INF/services/mypackage.Foo

```
myotherpackage.ConcreteFoo
myotherpackage.subpackage.OtherConcreteFoo
```

and the jar of course has to contain the all the classes mentioned in this file, which have to be non-abstract classes with a constructor that take no arguments.

---

The following program would then create an instance of **all** implementations of the `Foo`-service, that the `URLClassLoader` can find (i.e. allso including all implementations that are already in your classpath):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        URLClassLoader urlloader = new URLClassLoader(
                      new URL[]{
                            // one example of a local jar file added
                            new File("../FooImplementations/dist/FooImplementations.jar").toURI().toURL()
             });

        for (Foo foo : ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class, urlloader)) {
            // do something with foo e.g.
            foo.addAlgo("Hello World!");
        }

    }

}
```

As for finding the urls again after restarting the program:

- save the urls to a file, read the file on application startup and use the above approach to get the Foo, or
- copy/move the jars to a folder that is in the classpath when you start the program. (Class can then be loaded with the default `ClassLoader` and `ServiceLoader.load(Class)`)

If it isn't possible to create the instances of Foo with a no-parameter-constructor you can still choose to use the abstract factory pattern loading factories for `Foo` instead of `Foo`s directly (Which may also not be a bad idea, if you have to create multipe instances of each `Foo` service).